# Lombok builder pattern with jackson JsonProperty

Tags: java, jackson, pojo, lombok, jackson-databind

I have constructed a Java Object using lombok with builder pattern. But, I am getting the following exception when trying to deserialize a Java object using  Jackson. This occurs for fields which has `@JsonProperty` annotation.

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "user_name" (class User$UserBuilder), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "userName", "userId"])
>    at [Source: (String)"{"userId":1,"user_name":"username"}"; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: User$UserBuilder["user_name"])

Code Used :

```
public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        User user = User.builder()
                .userName("username")
                .userId(1)
                .build();
        System.out.println(user);
        String string = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
        System.out.println(string);
        user = objectMapper.readValue(string, User.class);
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}


@JsonDeserialize(builder = User.UserBuilder.class)
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class User {
    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    @NonNull
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty
    private int userId;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class UserBuilder {

    }
}
```

Kindly help me solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: The flip side of this is when you want Jackson to ignore extra keys in the JSON: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You get this error because Jackson doesn't know how to map `user_name` to any of your `UserBuilder` fields.

You need `@JsonProperty("user_name")` on the `userName` field of `UserBuilder` too, like that:

```
@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
public static class UserBuilder {

    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    @NonNull
    private String userName;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As of Lombok v1.18.16, you should be able to use the @Jacksonized annotation.

```
@Data
@Jacksonized
@Builder
public class Pojo {

    @JsonProperty("package")
    String pkg;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your mapper need to have a means of creating User class.

You could use constructor:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
class User {
  @JsonProperty("user_name")
  @NonNull
  private String userName;

  private int userId;
}
```

... or point it to builder as per [Tomasz Linkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032415/tomasz-linkowski)'s answer

Comment: For me, the most suitable format was using builder pattern. I didn't wanted to use a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

try update version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
    </dependency>
```